# how I can have a controller, which can pass (return) some model to _Layout.cshtml. view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a file index.cshtml which is auto generated by EF (code first). Following code is working fine in that file

```
@model IEnumerable<dyescan.Models.MyMainMenuItem>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemText)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LinkAction)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LinkController)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

But When I copy pasted the code in _layout.cshtml, I am unable to use this Model there.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I get above error in this line `@foreach(var item in Model)`. Following is my code in _Layout.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<dyescan.Models.MyMainMenuItem>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.ItemText,item.LinkAction,item.LinkController)</li>
}
```

**Update**

So I tried to follow th comments this way. I made a Controller `Shared` (folder name) and in that controller I made an action `_Layout` (file name of the view). now it returns dbContex.MyMainMenuItems.. to the view

But still unable to make a controller for _Layout.. to pass it a model for my menuitems

Comment: Well are you returning any objects when displaying your layout?

Comment: In your controller, are you returning `View(model)`?

Comment: Oh I should try to do that first.. Thanks for the good guidence

Comment: I have updated my question. I am still unable to have a controller which could pass a model to _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

When you use model in cshtml view, your Action method return model like :-

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var items = themes.Select(o => new SelectListItem {Text = o, Value = o, Selected = o == theme});
      return View(items);
    }
```

When Action method return model it is bind to view. so in above code items will be bind to index.cshtml.
If you try to access this model in _Layout.cshtml it will give error.

Comment: See my update please. I am unable to pass a model to _Layout from any controller => how i can have a controller, which can pass a model to _Layout.cshtml. I can do for anyother normal view.

Comment: You can use viewBag or viewData to pass model but in this case you have to pass it from every action method.

Comment: you really don't want your _Layout to take a model